# How to create Flipboard like topic selection page for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, selection

I am working on a iOS application where during onboarding, user should see options to select topics of interest. Based on topics chosen user will later see information related.

I need to understand

**1)** how to create such page in iOS app? should i be using UICollectionView?

**2)** what kind of programming (most likely server side) to be done to make it work among all users using it?

**3)** Is there any open source/tools/sample code available to do this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You can refer this link for designing the page-> https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tltagscontrol

Comment: Hello @umesh you got solution?